# In which case is an array faster

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative

I have a huge list of objects (e.g. I call them messages). Every message contains an array (e.g. I name them user) with 2, 3 or 4 strings (userids).

If I loop trough all messages I want to check in every message whence a userid is in the array or not. At which count of items in the array it would be faster to use an associative array² instead of a normal array¹ (*regardless the time for creating the associative array*)?

Certainly it takes time to create a hash (I think the associative array uses it), so I think an array with two items will be faster to loop...

Here is example one:

```
messages: {
  name: "msg1"
  users:[
    "1256",
    "1456"
  ]
}
```

Here is example two:

```
messages: {
  name: "msg1"
  users:{
    "1256": true,
    "1456": true
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "associative arrays" in Javascript. Those things are called *objects.* Also, you could and should **benchmark** it to optimise for **your use case**.

Comment: In my opinion, the first example is the best approach to this.